# Joining columns on partial strings

Tags: sql, string, join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

There are probably multiple ways to do this or frame this question

I have two tables I would like to join.

Table A

```
ID                          Column1A              Column2A
56ade9.mobile.app.          1A_data               2A_data
ko9j77:web.source.          1A_data               2A_data
9eej:mobile.app.            1A_data               2A_data
pdfg6334df.web.source       1A_data               2A_data
gyu8ssl                     1A_data               2A_data
```

Table B

```
ID                          Column1B              Column2B
9eej                        1B_data               2B_data
56ade9                      1B_data               2B_data
gyu8ssl                     1B_data               2B_data
pdfg6334df                  1B_data               2B_data
ko9j77                      1B_data               2B_data
```

And I'd like to join on the ID columns for a result of: (the row order doesn't matter)

```
ID        Column1A Column2A Column1B Column2B
9eej
56ade9
pdfg633df
gyu8ssl
ko9j77
```

However the ID column in table A has additional, superfluous string characters which are delimitated by either a `.` or a `:`.

Some IDs in Table A will not have the superfluous strings added to the ID, such as the last row in Table A with ID `gyu8ssl`

The superfluous string sequence after the actual id in Table A is not consistent, and can be more than the examples I listed.

The actual id is not uniform in character length; however the first break in the alpha numeric sequence with a punctuation indicates the end of the actual ID which should be joined on.

Attempt:

I'm a bit stumped on how to approach this. I was looking at `STRING_SPLIT` but it seems to only take in one delimiter at a time and I don't think that will get me what I want. I'm actually kind of stymied.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The first step to solving this is writing a `SELECT` query for Table A that returns the `ID` values in a way that will match table B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select b.ID
, a.ColumnA1
, a.ColumnA1
, b.ColumnB1
, b.ColumnB2
from TableB b
  inner join TableA a
    on case 
         when replace(a.ID, ':', '.') like '%.%'
           then substring(a.ID, charindex('.', replace(a.ID, ':', '.')))
         else a.ID
       end = b.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

The first step to solving this is writing a `SELECT` query for Table A with an expression over the `ID` column such that the expression results match the values in table B. But I'll gloss over that part; I expect other answers here will be more than adequate to learn how to write this expression, even if they show it in an `ON` clause instead of the `SELECT` list.

Instead, I'll spend my time suggesting a better way to use this expression. Once you are confident in the accuracy of the expression, alter the table to add it as a *computed column*. This will allow you to make the column [`PERSISTED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-computed-column-definition-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#persisted), which can improve performance by saving from doing this work at run time every time you run the query. You can also index it, which can improve performance yet again.